# IMAGE inside a php string

Tags: php, string, image

How can I put a IMAGE inside a php string?

```
$this->html .= "image here";
```

If I put a image absolut patch or other options I get a

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Comment: Please show the code that causes errors. There should be no problem at all with something like `$this->html .= '<img src="whatever.jpg" />';`

Comment: Unexpected __what__?

Comment: Omg, it's work.
$this->html .='<img src="image.png" />';
the error was the cotes "... just change with '

Thank's !!!!